Getting "key" from hashMapOf
I want to get my keys from my hashMapOf but when I tried, my values come as well. How can I get just my keys?
val list = hashMapOf("element1" to "1" , "element2" to "2")
 
val random = Random
list.entries.elementAt(random.nextInt(list.keys.size))

I want to get just my keys from my hashMapOf.

I would never call a hashMap instance a list in my code. A map is a map is a map. The entries in a map are the key / value pairs. I mean, it is not hard to find, right?

If you want to retrieve only the keys from your map, use this:
list.keys

If you want one random key from the map, use this:
list.keys.random()

If you want one random value from the map, use this:
list.values.random()


hashMapOf creates an instance of HashMap which is a subtype of Map; and, there is keys property defined for Map interface.
So, to get random key from the map, you can use:
val list = hashMapOf("element1" to "1" , "element2" to "2")
val randomKey = list.keys.elementAt(random.nextInt(list.keys.size))

